# Java in array return incorrect value

Tags: java, android

i'm retrive data from server with JSON with this code :

```
String smsReceivedSender = "";
String receive_lastID = "";

String r = new JsonService(username, password, 0, 1, G.F_RECEIVE_SMS).request();
JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray(r);
JSONObject json_obj  = data_array.getJSONObject(0);
receive_lastID       = json_obj.getString("id_recived_sms");
smsReceivedSender    = json_obj.getString("mobile_number");
```

and i have class structure as :

```
public class ReceivedItemStructure {
    public String mLastID;
    public String mUserID;
    public String mSmsBody;
    public String mMobileNumber;
    public String mDate;
    public String mSenderName;
    public String mSmsNumber;
    public String mContactName;
}
```

after thiat for search into this class data i'm try to get item from that and save into new `ArrayList` such as :

```
ArrayList<String> items_array   = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ReceivedItemStructure rf:items){
     items_array.add(rf.getmLastID());
}
```

check data :

```
for (String rf:items_array){
   Log.e("items_array lastID value", rf);
}
```

now i want to search `receive_lastID` into item_array `array` by :

```
Log.e("Received lastID", receive_lastID);
if( Arrays.asList(items_array).contains(receive_lastID) ) {
  countSMS++;
}
```

check result:

```
Log.e("Result Check: ", String.valueOf(Arrays.asList(items_array).contains(receive_lastID)));
```

but thats return `false` allwayes

LogCat:

```
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/Received lastID﹕ 30360152
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30360087
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30360052
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30360015
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30359363
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30359353
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30359273
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30359195
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30354338
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30354260
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/items_array lastID value﹕ 30353823
10-08 08:15:25.100    2817-2817/ir.tsms E/Result Check:﹕ false
```

30360152 lastId is not in `items_array` and that must be return false. but alwayes return `false` if `items_array` have that or dont have that.

whats my code problem?

Answer (score 1):

`items_array` is a `List<String>`, so as you call `Arrays.asList(items_array)`, which you call on arrays normaly you will get a List of your List `List<List<String>>`, this wont work ;D
Try using a foreach loop to search your list, or if you use java 8 use .stream() e.g. 
`items_array.stream().filter(o -> o.mLastID == receive_lastid).findFirst().get()`

And read some about clean code maybe, your public vars + getters seem strange to me.

edit: or just use contains()....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
String.valueOf(Arrays.asList(items_array).contains(receive_lastID))
```

Check every string manually

```
for (String text : items_array) {
    if (text.equals(receive_lastID))
        return true;
}
return false;
```

See [why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/2274724)

Answer (score 0):

Just use items_array.indexOf(receive_lastID)!=-1 like this

```
Log.e("Result Check: ", String.valueOf(items_array.indexOf(receive_lastID)!=-1));
```

Comment: This will work. He has mentioned ArrayList for items_array. Please check his code.

Comment: touche, i deserve stoning sentence